# Sending message from end of route to beginning of route

Tags: apache-camel

How do I send a message from the end of a route to the beginning of the route, ie from a producer endpoint to a consumer endpoint?

My producer endpoint is a socket server and once in a while one of the connected clients sends a message that needs to be forwarded to the other end of things.

`from("socks:client:localhost:3456").to("socks:server:localhost:3333");`

I'm stuck in `messageReceived` in the following code:

```
public class SocksProducer extends DefaultAsyncProducer {

private List<Channel> connectedClients = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Channel>();

public SocksProducer(SocksEndpoint socksEndpoint, int port) {
    super(socksEndpoint);
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", 1048576);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.sendBufferSize", 1048576);
    bootstrap.getPipeline().addLast("encode", new StringEncoder());
    bootstrap.getPipeline().addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
    bootstrap.getPipeline().addLast("echo", new ClientDataHandler());
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
}

@Override
public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback arg1) {
    String msg = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    connectedClients.forEach((channel) -> channel.write(msg));
    return true;
}

class ClientDataHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

    @Override
    public void channelClosed(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
            throws Exception {
        super.channelClosed(ctx, e);
        connectedClients.remove(ctx.getChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
            ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        super.channelConnected(ctx, e);
        connectedClients.add(ctx.getChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
        Exchange exchange = getEndpoint().createExchange();
        exchange.getIn().setBody(e.getMessage());
        // try {
        // getProcessor().process(exchange);
        // } finally {
        // // log exception if an exception occurred and was not handled
        // if (exchange.getException() != null) {
        // getExceptionHandler().handleException(
        // "Error processing exchange", exchange,
        // exchange.getException());
        // }
        // }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        log.error("", e.getCause());
        e.getChannel().close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you have a copy of Camel in Action book, read chapter 10, section 10.6

Comment: Claus, I guess I will have to buy a copy of your book then :-) Got inspired by https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction/blob/master/chapter10/scalability/src/main/java/camelinaction/ErpProducer.java

Comment: @ClausIbsen when is the revised edition coming out?